# How to run prolog on swipl and return all the traces in one go

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

1: If one query ie. `a(X).` returns multiple answers, how can I let the program return all the answers and the trace in one go.

2: How can I run a program auto matically i.e  print all answers of `a(X).` when I load the `.pl` file to the swipl i.e. after the comman

```
% swipl -f foo.pl
```

then it return all the answer of `X`

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need [leash](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=leash/1) as well as trace

```
swipl -s f.pl -g "leash(-all),trace,numbers(X),print(X),nl,fail." -t halt
% /home/carlo/.plrc compiled 0.04 sec, 1,439 clauses
% /home/carlo/prolog/f.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
   Call: (6) numbers(_G1453)
   Call: (7) between(1, 10, _G1453)
   Exit: (7) between(1, 10, 1)
   Exit: (6) numbers(1)
   Call: (6) print(1)
1
   Exit: (6) print(1)
   Call: (6) nl

   Exit: (6) nl
   Call: (6) fail
   Fail: (6) fail
   Redo: (7) between(1, 10, _G1453)
   Exit: (7) between(1, 10, 2)
   Exit: (6) numbers(2)
   Call: (6) print(2)
2
   Exit: (6) print(2)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple file with simple clause:

```
$> cat f.pl
numbers(X) :-
  between(1,10,X).
```

You can use `-g` option for setting goal:

```
$> swipl -s f.pl -g "numbers(X),print(X),nl,fail." -t halt.
% .../f.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: How do I get all the traces as well? I tried
swipl -s f.pl -g "trace, numbers(X),print(X),nl,fail." -t halt.
but it does require me to press enter